# Stored procedure calling another stored procedure hangs for a long time

Tags: sql-server, loops, stored-procedures

I have one stored procedure for which I get what I want for a particular customer. It comes back with 20 rows...

What I need to do is call this stored procedure for 20 customers one or more and then return the entire result set. I have the following but it just hangs and says executing.. I'm wondering what I have wrong...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getAllTotals] -- This stored procedure is new
@pDt1 datetime, @pDt2 datetime, @pStore int
AS 
BEGIN
   DECLARE @AccountTbl table (AccountID int );
   DECLARE @TotalTbl table (AccountID int, col1 varchar(100), col2  varchar(100) );

   DECLARE @accountID  int

   --cache all accountid INTO cursor AccountID_cursor
   DECLARE AccountID_cursor CURSOR FOR
       SELECT Storeid   
       FROM tblStore  
       WHERE StoreID = 111 OR storeid = 933

   OPEN AccountID_cursor;

   FETCH NEXT FROM AccountID_cursor INTO @accountID;

   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN     
      --insert total amount info to tmp table @TotalTbl
      insert @TotalTbl
         EXEC [dbo].[rptTransactions06192012_royal]
              @pDt1 = @pDt1, @pDt2 = @pDt2, @pStore = @accountID
   END

   --Send temp table results to front end as.
   SELECT * FROM @TotalTbl
END
```

Does that make sense?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You never instruct the cursor to grab the next row.

```
FETCH NEXT FROM AccountID_cursor INTO @accountID;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN

    --insert total amount info to tmp table @TotalTbl

insert @TotalTbl

  EXEC [dbo].[rptTransactions06192012_royal]
    @pDt1 = @pDt1,
    @pDt2 =@pDt2,
    @pStore   = @accountID

FETCH NEXT FROM AccountID_cursor INTO @accountID;

END
```

Also, keep in mind that cursoirs are notoriously slow.

Comment: Thank you! I should have seen that!

Comment: @DaleK trying to figure out how to "accept" It.

Comment: @LGuess tou could read the help :) but its the checkmark on the LHS of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As in any loop cycle you need to move to the next item at the end of each cycle, or it will be infinite loop.

For cursor instruction to move to the next item is "FETCH NEXT", you will need just copy initial load line to the end of the cursor loop, so it grabs next row once finished.